# Warcraft Reign of Chaos

Tags: warcraft-3

I can't defeat Chapter 7 Archimonde's Ascent no matter what I try and I'm not playing on difficult.I read one guys post about putting ballistae in the trees of the human base, but sure can't figure out where he's talking about? I'm playing on slow too. I had no problem going through the entire campaign until this last mission. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It would help if you include some details on what you've tried, and if there's a particular part of the level giving you trouble. Providing a link to the post you mentioned would also be really helpful, as someone might be able to clear up the confusion you're having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I win "Twilight of the Gods" final mission in Warcraft 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/how-do-i-win-twilight-of-the-gods-final-mission-in-warcraft-3)